# Using the trace to simplify the sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, matrix-equations, trace

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the iterative closest point algorithm based on this [paper](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/spring07/cps296.2/scribe_notes/lecture24.pdf). The expansion of (24.14) to (24.15) is giving me trouble.

I'm wondering how we go from

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n ||Ra_i' - b_i'||^2$$

to

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n||a_i'||^2 - 2tr(R\sum_{i = 1}^na_i'b_i'^T) + \sum_{i = 1}^n||b_i'||^2$$

For context: $a_i'$ and $b_i'$ are $n \times 1$ vectors and $R$ is an $n \times n$ rotation matrix.

I managed to get this far:

\begin{align}
 \sum_{i = 1}^n ||Ra_i' - b_i'||^2 \\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n (Ra_i' - b_i')^T(Ra_i' - b_i') \\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n(a'^T_iR^T - b_i'^T)(Ra_i' - b_i') \\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^na'^TR^TRa'_i - a_i'^TR^Tb_i' - b_i'^TRa_i' + b_i'^Tb'i\\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n||a_i||^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n[a_i'^TR^Tb_i' + b_i'^TRa_i'] + \sum_{i = 1}^n||b_i||^2
\end{align}

but then I'm not sure how to factor in the trace. I assume we're using the fact that $tr(A^TB) = tr(B^TA)$ and it's written as $tr(AB^T)$ in the equation I've referenced, which is also equivalent [I'm taking $A = Ra_i'$ and $B = b_i'$].

Comment: The equation is not correct, $||x||^2=x^Tx$, you need to remove the norm on the RHS.

Comment: @PC1 You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is cyclic so $\mathrm{tr}(ABC)=\mathrm{tr}(BCA)=\mathrm{tr}(CAB)$, for any matrix $A$, $B$, and $C$ (as long as dimensions are compatible).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property

In your situation, when you develop the norm, you get the factor $(b'_i)^T Ra'_i$, which we can rewrite as a trace: $\mathrm{tr}((b'_i)^T Ra'_i)=\mathrm{tr}(R  a'_i (b'_i)^T)$

EDIT:
The terms ${a'_i}^TR^Tb'_i$ and ${b'_i}^TRa'_i$ are actually the same as they are $1\times1$ matrices. Taking the transpose doesn't change the value. Taking the trace also doesn't change their value. Once we have taken the trace, we can do a cyclic permutation and find the result.

Comment: That makes sense -- the part I don't understand is how
$ \sum AB = \sum tr(AB) $, where is the trace coming from?

You've stated that we get the factor $(b'_i)^T Ra'_i$ but I'm not sure I understand why we can rewrite that term as a trace since that's simply considering the sum of the diagonal entries?

Comment: This is likely a gap on my part with the definition of the norm for a matrix.

Comment: Ah, ok I think I've got it. Is it right to say that we're using the Frobenius norm here and so $||A||^2 = tr(AA^T) = tr(A^TA)$ and so $\sum ||A||^2 = \sum tr(A^TA) = tr(\sum A^TA)$. In which case, the norm is missing from my earlier question with $AB$ --- in other words, the trace appears because it's part of the definition for the norm.

Comment: I'll do an edit to provide more details.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense — I was missing the fact that they were scalars (1x1).